# A-frame animation position

Tags: aframe

I want to make an animation for a box, which makes the box is coming closer and closer to the user. I tried this, but this doesn't worked for me:

```
<a-entity id="enemy">
 <a-box material="src: #texture_4" width="0" height="15" depth="4" transparent="true" opacity="0.75" position="0 0 -150" rotation="0 100 0" scale="2 0.5 3"></a-box>
 <a-animation atribute="position" to="0 0 0" fill="forwards"></a-animation>
</a-entity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attribute` was misspelled.

```
<a-animation attribute="position" to="0 0 0" fill="forwards"></a-animation>
```

And you need to animate the box, not the box's parent. The code you have is animating enemy from 0 0 0 to 0 0 0.

```
<a-entity>
  <a-box><a-animation/></a-box>
</a-entity>
```

Comment: but this also doesn't working, the box doesn't moving

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: can I control the speed of this animation?

Comment: @gaboraron, yes, using the "dur" property of the animation. There's an example on the aframe docs here: https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/animation.html
<a-box position="-1 1.6 -5" animation="property: position; to: 1 8 -10; dur: 2000; easing: linear; loop: true" color="tomato"></a-box>